# Can't install puttygen (tool for generating ssh key in .ppk format)

Tags: ssh, putty, kali-linux, ssh-keys

Here is what I have tried, I have installed putty:

> root@kali:~# putty
>
> (putty:2859): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_box_gadget_distribute: assertion
>   'size >= 0' failed in GtkScrollbar
>
> (putty:2859): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_box_gadget_distribute: assertion
>   'size >= 0' failed in GtkScrollbar
>
> (putty:2859): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_box_gadget_distribute: assertion
>   'size >= 0' failed in GtkScrollbar root@kali:~# apt-get install
>   puttygen Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done E: Unable to locate package puttygen

Comment: Would it be easier for you to generate the ssh key from elsewhere and copying the file in? Kali Linux is really not for general use and you will find lots of issue trying to do normal work. You probably need to do a fair bit of work just trying to get puttygen installed in the first place. Edit: Puttygen is not part of putty. puttygen is in `putty-tools`.

Comment: NB https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me

Answer (score 1):

I think this will sort it out your issue.

**INSTALLATION**

In some Linux distributions, the puttygen tool needs to be installed separately from the Putty client. For example, in Debian Linux, the following command will install it:

```
sudo aptitude install putty-tools
```

**CREATING A NEW KEY PAIR FOR AUTHENTICATION**

To create a new key pair for authentication from the command line, use something like:

```
puttygen -t rsa -b 2048 -C "user@host" -o keyfile.ppk
```

It is strongly recommended that a passphrase be used for key files intended for interactive use. Key files used for automation (e.g., with WinSCP should generally have an empty passphrase.

**INSTALLING THE PUBLIC KEY AS AN AUTHORIZED KEY ON A SERVER**

With both Tectia SSH and OpenSSH servers, access to an account is configured by generating a public key, copying the public key to the server, and adding the public key to a `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

To extract the public key, use:

```
puttygen -L keyfile.ppk
```

Then log into the server, edit the `authorized_keys` file with your favorite editor, and cut-and-paste the public key output by the above command to the authorized_keys file. Save the file. Configure PuTTY to use your private key file (here `keyfile.ppk`). Then test if login works. See configuring public key authentication for PuTTY.

**CHANGING THE PASSPHASE OF A KEY**

It is recommended that all SSH keys be regenerated and changed periodically. The Universal SSH Key Manager can automate this. Just changing the passphrase is no substitute, but it is better than nothing. These instructions can also be used to add a passphrase to a key that was created without one.

Use the following command to change the passphrase:

```
puttygen keyfile.ppk -P
```

This will prompt for the new passphrase, and write the result back to keyfile.ppk with the new passphrase.

**EXPORTING A PRIVATE KEY TO TECTIA SSH OR OPENSSH**

It is rarely necessary to export a private key from PuTTY to Tectia SSH or OpenSSH. However, the process is described here, as it can sometimes be necessary when, for example, an application is moved to Linux in the cloud and the destination server of a file transfer cannot easily be reconfigured to change an authorized key.

Tectia SSH and OpenSSH both support the OpenSSH private key file format, so using that key file format is described here. Tectia SSH also supports certain other formats.

To convert an existing PuTTY private key for Tectia or OpenSSH, use the command:

```
puttygen keyfile.ppk -O private-openssh -o keyfile
```

Then copy keyfile to the `.ssh` directory on the host where Tectia or OpenSSH will be run.

**COMMAND LINE OPTIONS**

The basic command line of PuTTYgen:

Specifies a key file to read or a key type and size to generate.
Optional action to perform (e.g., change passphrase)
Optional output type and output file.
The basic command line is:

```
puttygen [-t keytype [-b bits] [-q] | keyfile]
         [-C new-comment] [-P]
         [-O output-type | -p | -l | -L]
         [-o output-file]
```

Link:

[PUTTYGEN ON LINUX - SSH KEY GENERATOR](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/linux/puttygen)

Comment: Link-only isn't good, but copy/pasting the entire article isn't good either. (For copyright reasons as well.) Try to quote only the relevant parts.

Comment: how do you get to know it copy pasted @grawity

Comment: [Good question.](https://i.imgur.com/f1F5elp.png)